# Calling a Sql procedure from vb.net in infopath form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to execute the below code to call the sql procedure from infopath form using the vb.net,i debugged and checked for the Errors but code is executing properly and am facing problem to retrieve the output message received after executing the procedure.

Please help me to fix these issue ASAP

thanks

```
Try
         Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source= XXXX;Initial Catalog= XXXXX;Integrated Security=true")
         Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
         Dim dr As SqlDataReader
         con.Open()
         cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
         cmd.CommandText = "Procedure Name"
         cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = "XXX" 
         cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CustID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)).Value = "XXX"  
         cmd.Connection = con
         dr = cmd.Executereader()
         dr.Read()
         If dr.HasRows Then
             MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0))
         End If
                con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

My Sql procedure:

```
enter code here

Create procedure Test_Infopath

@Name varchar(50),
@CustID Varchar(20)
      AS 

      Declare @Condition INT
      SELECT @Condition = CustID FROM temp_infopath WHERE CustID = @CustID
      IF @CustID= @Condition
      BEGIN 
                Print 'Customer ID already Exists'
      END
      Else 
                Print 'Submit the form to insert the data'
```

Comment: Do you really have a procedure name with a space or that name is just a placeholder?

Comment: The ExecuteReader return the result of your last SELECT statement inside the stored procedure. Your code should work if there is a select (just apply the test HasRows before trying to read anything)

Comment: If HasRows returns false then there is no row to read. I think that you need to add to your question the code of the procedure that you think is returning 'messages'

Comment: but my procedure is returning the message when am trying in sql window with same parameters so how to resolve these then??

Comment: I don't understad what you mean by 'message'. To have `HasRows` return true, your procedure should return the rows obtained by a SELECT (a.k.a. records) not a generic string message. That's not returned by the SqlDataReader

Comment: see my proc result once if i execute my proc it will give the result as 'Customer ID already Exists'

Comment: Please add to your question the stored procedure text. I think that will help me a lot to understand what we are talking about

Comment: In my proc i have only one condtion if conditon is true am printing some value and if false vise versa

Comment: Sorry steve not able to attach the text file and i have added below to the code can u pls look once

Comment: if you dont mind can we have quick chat please some where as per your bandwith

Comment: Thanks after changing the proc do i need to change any thing in vb code??

Comment: Now i changed the proc as suggested and changed the datareader to Scalar changed the code as suggested but its throwing an Error Now in catch "unable to cast object of type 'System.string' to type system.data.sqlclient.SqlDatareader'

Comment: Please recheck my code. I don't use the DataReader anymore. I have made a slip using the syntax fo C# but the concept is: ExecuteScalare returns an object and, in your case the object returned is a string not a DataReader.

Comment: By the way please add the comments directly to my answer below, not at the question

Comment: Thanks very much for your help now am able to retrive the message

Comment: I have one more question so can i create new Question are can i ask here its just a small Question

Comment: A new question is better, because it gets more attention and you could get faster response time. A reference to this question, if needed, will also help

Comment: ok only small Q here is how to catch the result of nonQuery                        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to return the message in your stored procedure, not a a record.
However the SqlDataReader and other methods of ADO.NET are thought to return records not message strings.
I suggest you to change your procedure in this way

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Test_Infopath
    @Name varchar(50),
    @CustID Varchar(20)
    AS 

    Declare @Condition INT
    SELECT @Condition = CustID FROM temp_infopath WHERE CustID = @CustID

    IF @CustID= @Condition
        SELECT 'Customer ID already Exists'
    Else 
        SELECT 'Submit the form to insert the data'
```

Now the SqlDataReader will see the message as a record returned by SELECT
By  the way, when you return a single record composed by a single row, the usual way to code this scenario is through the ExecuteScalar method of the SqlCommand, without involving another object instance like the SqlDataReader.

```
cmd.Connection = con
Dim message = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
MessageBox.Show(message)
```

Comment: thanks now its work fine am able to retrieve the message from procedure and my problem is solved.Thanks very much for your help